# Vespertino-vocabulary use

Tags: vocabulario, significado-en-contexto

I have been reading [an article](https://elpais.com/salud-y-bienestar/2023-11-08/cinco-minutos-mas-por-favor-es-recomendable-utilizar-la-funcion-posponer-del-despertador.html) in "El Pais" by Adrián Cordellat.

Anyway, the sentence is

> [...] cuando se tiene inercia del sueño, ya sea por ser **vespertino** o por ir algo privado de sueño, “probablemente sea mejor este despertar progresivo a lo largo de 30 minutos que hacerlo de forma brusca cuando llegas a tu hora límite, pues te va a costar más entrar plenamente en una vigilia atenta”

Does "ser vespertino" mean a night-owl here?
I know what "un búho" and "noctambulo" are.

I have checked the RAE and other dictionaries and it seems not to mean this but rather it is related to evening time. So, I am wondering is this a high-register way of expressing that?

Comment: To be a night person, to be a morning person. We have no fancy Latinesque way of saying it, afaik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Personas matutinas y personas vespertinas

> Algunas personas alcanzan su mayor rendimiento en las mañanas y durante el resto del día se debilitan o dispersan, mientras que otras funcionan de manera contraria. Es por eso que se suele diferenciar entre las personas de hábitos matutinos (personas matutinas o mañaneras) y las personas de hábitos vespertinos (personas vespertinas o nocturnas), dependiendo de cuál sea la franja horaria de mayor energía, actividad y capacidad de concentración.

Fuente: https://concepto.de/matutino-y-vespertino/#ixzz8J9jtVrmY

Comment: Those answers explain perfectly